# Java и 3d: какие библиотеки и примеры программ?

Tags: java, 3d

Слышал ява сильна для сети, многопоточности, для нее куча библиотек.

1. А как она для написания браузерных 3D приложений?
2. Насколько она поддерживает openGL и DirectX?
3. Есть ли браузерные 3d игры или программы на Java?

Answer (score 3):

1. Применима.
2. За директ не скажу, а для OpenGL есть [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/)
3. [Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/). Вполне успешный проект.

Еще можно посмотреть на [обертку](http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/) для довольно популярного графического движка OGRE.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё отличный метаязык написанный на яве - Processing. сайт - processing.org. Отличнейшая вещь!! Работает на OpenGL, но можно и DirectX подключить